# How to append multiple scanned barcode result data in a page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a application in which I have to scan a barcode and show it to other page. The Initially requirement was for one product only but now the requirement is to show multiple scanned barcode result in existing `div`. I have managed to show for one product barcode scan result in a page using following code in my controller.js:

```
.controller('ScanCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {
$scope.title = "How to scan an inventory";

$scope.startScan = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Scanning Barcode....'
    });

    $timeout(function() {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        window.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {

                $rootScope.barcoderesults = [{

                    Barcode: result.text

                }];

                alert('We got a barcode');
                $state.go('page.scan-detail');

                /*if($scope.startScan){
                    $rootScope.barcoderesults.push({Barcode:$rootScope.barcoderesults});
                    $rootScope.barcoderesults = '';
                };*/

            }, 
            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            }

        );
    }, 1000, false);
}

})
```

and this is my html page where I am calling that `barcoderesults` variable using `ng-repeat`:

```
<ion-view title="Scan Result">
  <ion-content class="has-header padding-top">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <div ng-repeat="barcoderesult in barcoderesults">Barcode: {{barcoderesult.Barcode}}</div>
     </div>
     <div class="item item-content">
    <!-- Scan Button -->
      <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="startScan()">Continue Scan</button>
      <center><h3>OR</h3></center>
      <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="">Checkout</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now the scenario is after scanning the barcode from screen 1 I navigate to screen 2 where I show the result and in screen 2 I have **Continue Scan** button, which is using the same function `ng-click="startScan()"`. I was trying following code in my same controller to show multiple results but couldn't achieved:

```
if($scope.startScan){
                    $rootScope.barcoderesults.push({Barcode:$rootScope.barcoderesults});
                    $rootScope.barcoderesults = '';
                };
```

Can some one please help me on this as I am new in AngularJS. I am using AngularJS + Ionic + Cordova. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does screen 1 has any responsibility in addition to initiate barcode scan? Can you have single storage for all scanned barcodes across all application?

Comment: Can you remove screen 1 and instead of it add custom directive for barcode scan onto screen 2?

Comment: Yes from screen 1 I start scanning my 1st product barcode after getting the result it navigate to screen 2 where I have option to continue scan or checkout. If user choose continue scan the result should be append below the first result.

Comment: The question was: do you need the screen 1 if screen 2 can do barcode scan itself? And do you need to have common storage for scanned barcodes in application?

Comment: As per requirement I need screen 1 to start scan 1st barcode and after that from screen 2 I need to have option to continue scan. Yes I need common storage for scanned barcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of thisngs: if you need to share some state between controllers, then you need to save this state in service (there are more options with nested controllers, but this not such case). 
So, you need a servie which should do scanning and holds scanned barcodes:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('barcodeService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$window',
      function($q, $timeout, $window) {
        var scanTimeout = 1000,
            barcodes = [];

        return {
          barcodes: barcodes,
          scanBarcode: scanBarcode
        };

        function scanBarcode() {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          var rejectByTimeout = $timeout(function() {
            deferred.reject('timeout rejection');
          }, scanTimeout, false);

          $window.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function(result) {
              deferred.resolve(result);
            },
            function(error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
            });

          return deferred.promise.then(function(barcode){
            if(barcodes.indexOf(barcode) == -1){
              barcodes.push(barcode);
            }

            return barcode;
          });
        }
      }
    ]);
}());
```

Also, let's create custom directive for invoking barcode scan to prevent polluting controllers:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp').directive('barcodeScan', ['$log', 'barcodeService',
    function($log, barcodeService) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: "<button ng-click='doScan()' >Scan Barcode</button>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.doScan = function() {
            barcodeService.scanBarcode()
              .then(function(barcode) {
                $log.info('Barcode scan succeeded with result: ' + barcode);
              }, function(error) {
                $log.error('Barcode scan failed with error: ' + error);
              });
          };

          if (attrs.initialScan.toLowerCase() === 'true') {
            scope.doScan();
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
}());
```

With this two pices in place you can write your controller as:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeController', 
  ['$scope', 'barcodeService',
    function($scope, barcodeService) {
      $scope.barcodes = barcodeService.barcodes;
    }
  ]);
})();
```

and view template:

```
<div ng-controller='HomeController'>
  <barcode-scan barcodes='barcodes' initial-scan='true' ></barcode-scan>
  <hr />
  <ul ng-repeat='barcode in barcodes' >
    <li ng-bind='barcode'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Draw your attention on `initial-scan` attribute of the `barcodeScan` directive. When this attribute has `true` value, barcode scanning initiated immediately after directive loaded into view.
Actually, you can put this directive onot a screen 2 and remove screen 1 at all. All the way, with single screen 2 or both screen 1 and screen 2, barcodes will be shared between controllers.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QicXh4?p=preview)

Also, as an additional option, you can use `barcodeService.scanBarcode` method for `resolve` option of screen 2 route. This way, when user will be navigated on screen 2, it's controller will receive scanned barcode: [Plunker with screen2 route resolve](http://plnkr.co/edit/BtsnrA?p=preview)

Comment: I tried your method in my existing code but it doesn't work for me my whole app doesn't run :(

Comment: Did you change module name in my code to your module name?

Comment: Yes I have changed module name in your code but still didn't work.

Comment: Is there any other way without using service?

Comment: Hi Yuriy, I have achieved the same result as using your example in my code. It is working fine in browser like plunker but I have to use my android device achieve the same result. Once I click on Scan Barcode button from my android device it is not detecting my device camera to scan any barcode. Do you have any idea?